# Use FB.ui with possibility to choose on which page to share

Tags: facebook, share, fb.ui

I made a **SPA** (single page app) with dynamics articles (filled with javascript). So I used **FB.ui** so as to dynamically fill facebook options, like this :

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    display: 'popup',
action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            'og:url': overrideLink,
            'og:title': overrideTitle,
            'og:description': overrideDescription,
            'og:image': overrideImage
        }
    })
},
function (response) {});
});
```

But with this solution, it does'nt seem possible to have the *"share the content to the pages I manage"* option.
(with simple syntax - just href link - this option is activated)

I searched on a lot of forums and facebook dev doc but did'nt find. If someone can help ! Thanks !

Comment: You can't use share_open_graph. Share real URLs that have og-tags on them

Comment: @tylerweir, of course I tried different solutions... I don't understand why you downvote because no attempt ? I tried with share method, or differents display, or old syntaxes (before action_properties), etc, but if I want to dynamically change parameters, it seems that I need to use this syntax (i'm not 100% sure, but this is what I understood on dev docs and forums) but this syntax doesn't allow to share on managed pages...

Comment: @WizKid when you say this, do you mean that it is not possible to share a SPA with dynamics tags ?

Comment: Share a URL that is dynamic. So url.php?foo=1 and url.php?foo=2 and then have the page include different tags depending on the URL.

Comment: ok, so something like url.php?og:url=<mylink>&og:title=<mytitle>&og:description=<mydesc>&og:image=<myimageurl> ?

Comment: I finally found this website http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript that explain it is not possible anymore... So I created dynamic pages, with good tags for facebook, but with "next" button which redirect to SPA (for human users... :)